# Firewall adding issuer - Peer's Certificate issuer not recognized

Tags: git, ssl, ssl-certificate, firewall

It seems our firewall is adding an extra issuer to all our SSL certificates `C=US,ST=STATE,L=CITY,O=COMPANY,OU=TECH DEPT,CN=SSL-COMPANY`
and I'm unsure how to get the issuer recognized. I've tried `ca-certificates` and importing with `update-ca-trust extract` after obtaining a pem from `openssl`. Yet git, wget, and curl all do not accept the issuer when i point those programs to the pem or ca-bundles.

Is there another way to accept an unrecognized issuer? Is this the same as creating an authority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was easier than i thought just took some correct researching. First extract the certificate authority from your browsers store. Then CD to the directory you placed it in. Then create the digital signature with this command.

```
sudo openssl x509 -in test.cer -inform DER -out /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/test.crt
```

Then run

```
sudo update-ca-trust extract
```

This command places the digital signature in your linux store. All if not all programs should locate the signature in the store.